# How to use duplicated, sort values, and pivot table to group the data w.r.t. cell value and keep the cell value that have occurred more than one time

Tags: python, pandas

I want group the data from the table according to 'name' column values and keep the information where the 'name' column values have occurred more than one time in the table. The following code works fine for the given small data table.

```
import pandas as pd
data={'Name':['Danny','Damny','Monny','Quony','Dimny','Danny'],
      'Email':['danny@gmail.com','danny@gmail.com','monny@gmail.com','quony@gmail.com','danny@gmail.com','danny@gmail.com'],
     'IBAN':['NLAMRO123456789','NLINGB126656723','BGFFEO128856754','NLAMRO123896763','DUDMRO567456722','NLRABO123456712']} #data with three columns
df=pd.DataFrame(data) #creation of dataframe
df['No Dutch Bank']=None #creation of extra column for analysis
df.loc[df['IBAN'].str.find('NL') == -1, 'No Dutch Bank']='ja'# to find rows, which contain non dutch bank numbers.
df_filt=df[['Name',"Email", "IBAN"]]#filtering columns needed in the final results
df_gb = df_filt[df_filt.duplicated(subset=['Name'], keep=False)].sort_values(by='Name', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)#filtering on a required column
piv_tab = pd.pivot_table(df_gb, index=['Name',"Email", "IBAN"])#applying pivot table
piv_tab
```

This works fine for original data of three columns and six rows. In practice I have data of thirty columns and thirty thousand (30000) rows. When I select three columns (Name, Email and IBAN) and run the same code, the code does not filter out occurrence of rows which appeared in the table only once.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything except for the pivot logic is correct and should work for larger dataset as well.

Another approach would be calculate the count of names, filter by count > 1, and merge the names back to this table via left join.

This way is more explicit in filter by count > 1, and is more flexible to support filter by count > 2 etc.

```
import pandas as pd

# count names
df_name = df_filt.groupby('Name')['Email'].count()

# get names with count > 1
df_name = df_name[df_name > 1].reset_index()

# merge filtered names back to original df to get filtered df
df_gb = pd.merge(df_name['Name'], df_filt, on=['Name'], how='left')

# sorting etc.
df_gb = df_gb.sort_values(by='Name', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

# and some pivot stuff
...
```